# does JPEG compression ensure only source colors in the file?

Tags: colors, compression, jpeg

If I have a restricted gamut of colors in my image (to adhere to a CMYK gamut), does saving my file as a JPEG ensure that no new colors are introduced into the saved file?  Since JPEG is lossy, and it sometimes looks like blended colors are used in the compression, I am concerned colors out of the gamut might be introduced.   Or are the colors used in compression limited to the palette of the source being compressed?

Comment: nope. jpg can introduce 'new' colors that are perceptually the same but have different rgb values, if it decides that doing so can increase compression levels.

Comment: Might want to ask this on http://photo.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not guaranteed. One of the aspects of "lossy" compression is that colours may be restored on decompression in a way that is different from the source. If you want precise colour reproduction, you will need to use a lossless format (eg. PNG).